# How can I enforce single instancing for my HoloLens applications?

Tags: unity, c#, vb.net, hololens

I am searching for a solution to avoid multiple instances of my application in HoloLens. How can I detect that there's one already running, and stop the new instance?

I am new to Unity and application development, I read that it's an OS problem (operative system) and it's not related to HoloLens? Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can force Unity to run a single instance of your application by ticking `Force Single Instance` in `Edit > Project Settings > Player > Resolution and Presentation`

[image: Screenshot of Project Settings window showing where to find the option]

Comment: thank you for your response but this option is only valid for pc, mac and lunix settings , in my case it is a UWP application and I haven't found this parameter in settings for universal windows platform